# Disable Scrollbar on Owner Drawn Listbox

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a owner drawn listbox to which I add a lot of items(and this takes time),
when the items are being added, the vertical scrollbar keeps on getting smaller,
I want to disable the scrollbar when I begin to add and then re enable it ..

I have tried--

```
LONG old_style=GetWindowLong(hPlayList,GWL_STYLE);
LONG new_style= old_style&~WS_VSCROLL; 
SetWindowLong(hPlayList,GWL_STYLE,new_style);
SetWindowPos(hPlayList,HWND_TOP,lstRc.left,lstRc.right,lstRc.right-lstRc.top,lstRc.bottom-lstRc.top,
        SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
UpdateWindow(hPlayList);
```

and

```
ShowScrollBar(hPlayList,SB_VERT,FALSE);
```

But the scrollbar is still shown when I add items,
the listbox is created like,

```
hPlayList = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, WC_LISTBOX, NULL,
               LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED |WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL |WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE|LBS_NOTIFY|LBS_HASSTRINGS,
                lbsPos.x, lbsPos.y,350, 400, hWnd, (HMENU) LIST_ID, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
```

and I use SendMessage() to add the items.

I had also tried,

```
ShowWindow(hPlayList,SW_HIDE);
```

and

```
SendMessage(hPlayList,WM_SETREDRAW,(WPARAM)FALSE,0);
```

Comment: here's a video i uploaded for the issue .. http://youtu.be/d6KyUC9SWiA

Comment: and the whole code... [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/7WY7wwTz) ... some of the code is redundant and commented.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`WM_SETREDRAW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message with `wParam (fRedraw)` set to `FALSE` before adding strings. when you are done set it to `TRUE` and `UpdateWindow` or `RedrawWindow`.

> This message can be useful if an application must **add several items to a list box**. The application can call this message with wParam set to FALSE, add the items, and then call the message again with wParam set to TRUE. Finally, the application can call RedrawWindow(hWnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_ERASE | RDW_FRAME | RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_ALLCHILDREN) to cause the list box to be repainted.

Comment: I had already tried WM_SETREDRAW, the window does not redraw, but the scroll bar animation takes place and listbox goes blank.